# Prevent std::function in gcc from allocating memory or increase threshhold

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, memory-management, std-function

Is there any way to prevent `std::function` in gcc from dynamically allocating memory for larger function objects?

I would have expected the following code to work without dynamic allocation:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

// replace operator new and delete to log allocations
void* operator new (std::size_t n) {
    std::cout << "Allocating " << n << " bytes" << std::endl;
    return malloc(n);
}
void operator delete(void* p) throw() {
    free(p);
}

  class TestPlate
  {
    private:
        int value;

    public:
        int getValue(){ return value; }
        void setValue(int newValue) { value = newValue; }

        int doStuff(const std::function<int()>& stuff) { return stuff(); }

  };

int main()
{
    TestPlate testor;
    testor.setValue(15);
    const std::function<int()>& func =  std::bind(&TestPlate::getValue, &testor);

    std::cout << testor.doStuff(func) << std::endl;
    testor.setValue(25);
    std::cout << testor.doStuff(func) << std::endl;
}
```

However it allocates 24 bytes. As far as I am able to tell this is because the pointer to method requires 16 bytes and the pointer to the class instance another 8 bytes. This seems to be either A larger than the internal memory available to the function object or B a plain bug.

I was wondering whether there are is any way to circumvent this type of behavior without changing the signature of the `std::function` or creating a lot of additional wrapper code.

Comment: Standard states that _Implementations are encouraged to avoid the use of dynamically allocated memory for small callable objects, for example, where f is an object holding only a pointer or reference to an object and a member function pointer_. Compilers do their best. If it doesn't fit your needs, well...

Comment: clang + libc++ isn't allocating any memory in your example (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52505806440111db)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately GCC's `function` only has space for a pointer to member function stored internally, so the result of your bind expression doesn't fit.

You can use a lambda expression instead though:

```
std::function<int()> f = [&]{ return testor.getValue(); };
```

This only requires space for a closure type containing a reference to `testor` (which is half the size of a pointer to member, and a third of the size of the bind result), and GCC defines that closure so it can be stored in a `std::function`.

Comment: @T.C. indeed I do - and that's what I tested. But not what I typed here for some reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the exceptionally skin-crawling `functional` header of libstdc++ (the default C++ library of GCC), I found out that it is in fact impossible to avoid heap allocations with its present implementation. It seems to have a special manager and invoker member that's heap-allocated, and it is required for the class to work. If you really want to look at the source, [here you go](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/functional#L1835), but there are definitely black arts and witchcraft going on there.

There is some functionality in the header that implies passing in [custom allocators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator) are planned, but they don't seem to be implemented at this time.

In the meantime, you could try [Boost.function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/function.html).

Comment: It will avoid heap allocation if the `__stored_locally ` condition is true. Unfortunately that is false for anything larger than a pointer to member function, so can't store that and a pointer to an object locally.