# How to lazily instantiate a functor argument passed in a function when calling it under some condition in C++14?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Assume that I have a function that abstracts some error-handling logic, it has argument which is a functor. Inside it, it calls this functor conditionally.

The function looks like this:

```
void HandleError(int err_code, std::function<void()> error_logger) {
  //...
  if (condition) {
    error_logger();
  }
  //...
}
```

But now a caller needs to construct the `error_logger` (consider a lambda) before calling this function. It is a little bit not optimal.

How to lazily instantiate the `error_logger` only when it's called when the condition is true?
Unfortunately, I can only use C++14. But boost library could be used.

Comment: A function that produces a function?

Comment: @AndyG It doesn't produce functor. The functor is passed in.

Comment: If you want to lazily instantiate the error logger, then you need to pass a function that when called, will construct and return your error logger function. Within your function, after you check for your condition, you'd call the argument once to construct the error logger, and then invoke the returned logger to actually log. Ergo, a function that produces a function.

Comment: Have you actually measured a perfomance hit you cannot pay. I assume creating a lambda is actually a lot less work then the actual logging. You could always queue a whole lambda + capture of values + timestamp + "the condition check" and let another thread pick it up later to do the actual condition check, message formatting and logging.

Comment: @AndyG That still requires the caller to construct a factory lambda.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Good point! I am actually refactoring the existing code. Logging has been there. Optimization of logging is a different topic.

Comment: With such interface you can change the caller, so it will construct the std::function only once, and the only change in your function will be to pass function parameter by reference(instead value)

Comment: @Christophe If you are refactoring, I have another tip. When I design my logging. I start without logging or even an abstract log interface. If a class needs to log message (or report things in any other way) I will create an abstract baseclass e.g. `my_class_report_itf` (with report_xyz_happened(args...)` and inject that at construction time of the code that needs to do the logging. Now I have the freedom to put anything in an implementation of that report interface, nothing for unit tests, or forwarding to the logging system of the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove std::function from interface, for example you want to guarantee, that there will be no heap memory allocation, you can write the code in this way, using the lambdas directly

```
template<typename LogFunc>
void HandleError(int err_code, LogFunc &&error_logger) {
//...
  if (condition) {
    error_logger();
  }
//...
}

HandleError( 0x10, [](){ // log } );
```

However there is no much sense to save the performance on std::function construction. Also there is an optimization, when the heap allocation is avoided ([for ex. for gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38667268/prevent-stdfunction-in-gcc-from-allocating-memory-or-increase-threshhold)).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Could you please explain why do you use a rvalue reference (`LogFunc &&`) here? Will use `LogFunc error_logger` work?

Comment: it is a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), in short it means, that the type can be deduced as either an rvalue or an lvalue reference.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy "creation" implies a **"function that produces the end object"**. When employing such a technique, you need to make sure that it's worth the trouble and by that I mean:

- The object being lazily instantiated is re-used. There's no point moving around an **"object producing function"** and conjure something into existence whenever you need it, only to end up with more instances than what you'd have if you were using a single object to begin with.
- The "thingy" that lazily instantiates your object is cheaper than the data itself. Objects with "heavy" constructors are one such case and you'll often see a pattern in legacy code where constructor is split from resource acquisition/initialization to allow conditionally calling the "heavy" stuff.
- The end object is initialized in a thread-safe manner

For the scope of this answer I'll show c++17 code, but should be easily portable to c++14 if you use `boost::optional` instead of its `std` counterpart while replacing `std::invoke` with simple function call syntax:

```cpp
template <class Fn>
struct lazy
{    
    using value_type = std::invoke_result_t<Fn>;
    
    lazy(Fn fun) : _function(std::move(fun))
    {
    }
    
    value_type const& operator*() const
    {
        std::call_once(_once, [&] {
            _data.emplace(std::invoke(_function));
        });
        return *_data;
    }
    
private:
    Fn _function;
    mutable std::once_flag _once;
    mutable std::optional<value_type> _data;
};
```

With `lazy`,

- the object having deferred "creation" is kept as an `optional` and only constructed upon "first use".
- construction is wrapped in `call_once` to avoid data races when multiple threads access a lazy object, because even "reading" can trigger construction
- the contained value is obtained (or created for the first access) by dereferencing the lazy object

The simple usage example is to show how this would work with a non callable class instance:

```cpp
int main ()
{
    lazy obj([] {
        HugeObject ret;
        /* fill the huge object */
        return ret;
    });
   
   use_or_not(obj);
   ...
   use_or_not(obj);   
}
```

In the series of `use_or_not` calls, the huge object might or might not be instantiated. After the first use, the `lazy obj` will contain a `HugeObject` and use it onwards:

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bf790913388a667)

[C++14 Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b5487079c7895eb)

Your specific case is to "lazily generate a function object". Well good news, that is still an object and use of `lazy` doesn't differ much:

```cpp
lazy obj([] {
    std::function<void()> ret;
    ret = [] { std::cout << "nada" << std::endl; };
        
    return ret;
});
```

[Lazily generate function object Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c42da3126c8aa9c9)

Since function objects are often more lightweight (unless they have to encapsulate a lot of data) please make sure you adhere to the rules mentioned at the beginning of the answer.

---

This is the first topic in the [C++ 2023 closing keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ceFEtCRIXk4). The lazy class is pretty much copied from there.